# R: histogram (short stacks)

Tags: r, histogram

I've got the following code:

```
boundaries = seq(0,1 , by=0.01)
hist(hoeveel_rommel_per_rapport,breaks=boundaries, col="red")
```

I get the following histogram:

[image]

At some places on the x-axis, there are some short stacks. For example between x = 0,2 and x = 0,21. Is there an explanation for this? Is  this caused by my code? Have I forgotten something in my code?

Comment: That's just the nature of histograms - some bins happen to not have many datapoints falling in them. You can adjust the number and the placement of the bins with  the `breaks` argument.

Answer (score 0):

In your code see `breaks=boundaries` the parameter `breaks` controls the breaks of histogram. In your case it is too small.